# tags autosuggestion seems to be bugged managing a tag containing "ss"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, autocomplete

It seems that the "ss" sequence is treated abnormally by the auto completition engine.

I noticed the issue typing "oss" and having the following suggestions:

> macosx (194)
>   centos (141)
>   osx    (122)
>   hosting (119)
>   postfinx (77)
>   web-hosting (65)

That is **not what one expects** of course

writing an additional "s" seems to make "osss" be treated as wanted ("oss") by the engine, resulting in the following, good, suggestions:

> moss (32)
>   jboss (16)
>   cross-platform    (7)
>   moss-2007 (5)
>   data-loss (3)
>   jboss-cache (1)

Comment: Confirmed. Even works with *one* s: Typing in "as" suggest any tag with an "a" in it.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed an old left over "trick", of removing the trailing S. I took it out of the code and will deploy later.

Answer (score -3):

I think the tagging system is very difficult to use if you choose things from the suggested list.

Just type in the tags and don't choose them.

Comment: I totally disagrre