# Can we have a "Bug Hunter" badge on MSO?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, tag-badges, bug-reports

I propose a new "**bug hunter**" silver (maybe gold?) badge to ppl who started a question explicitly signaling a BUG, the bug being confirmed and fixed.

I think is right to promote SO-SF-SU-MSO improvement.

Comment: You thin it will be a rare one, because most *bugs* are `by design`?

Comment: yes, I think that the network is very well organized and written, so I don't think that every day someone finds a real bug

Comment: SO prides itself on the number of "intentional" bugs in its source

Comment: Those aren't bugs but just undocumented features...

Comment: For some reason, I now have Steve Irwin's voice in my head reading this question to me. Crikey!

Comment: @LadybugKiller: That would just mean it is worth a gold badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this is a badge that's specific to Meta - not to the Trilogy sites.  Site-specific badges aren't a great idea, IMO.

Comment: Uhmm, I did not had thought about this aspect. I agree with you, so I close this post. +1 for you.

Comment: I realize this is a very old answer but since they created the [quorum](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/900/quorum) and [convention](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention) badges this reason may no longer be valid

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Actually, those can still be extended to other sites in the SE network since they each have their own meta sites and rep/badges is/are linked between main and meta. Stack Overflow is the odd one out here because its meta is considered the meta for the entirety of Stack Exchange (I think they're working on a separation).

Comment: For those who are interested by Yawus's comment: [yes, separation is in the works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).

Answer (score 2):

I always give what seem to be valid bug reports (and retag requests) an upvote, to reward those pointing things out and taking initiative.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, but it doesn’t seem to help; most of the community still closes and dismisses them.

Answer (score 1):

I see someone is a [little proud of their bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16023/tags-autosuggestion-seems-to-be-bugged-managing-a-tag-containing-ss). :)

Comment: eheh, LOL ... I think every open community lives on the "ego" of their members :P

Comment: I really think that this badge should exists, so if you want make it non retroactive and I'll not be badged until next bug I'll discover :)

Comment: Jeff Atwood or not, shouldn't this be a comment instead? :)

Comment: @StevenJeuris Well... meta is a little more relaxed. We all know that. And I think his point is that not everybody needs a badge: they're already proud.