# Rep reward for bug report

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bug-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a “Bug Hunter” badge on MSO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18039/can-we-have-a-bug-hunter-badge-on-mso)

I guess we should reward a genuine bug report with some rep on the original site. How does that sound

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you may need to use your rep to get more attention, according to [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq). :-)

> What if I really want someone to look
>   at my bug / feature request /
>   discussion?
>
> Put a bounty on it. This costs a
>   little reputation, but it will push
>   your post to the featured tab for 7
>   days and visually distinguish it from
>   other posts. It will get more
>   attention, but we can't guarantee it
>   will necessarily be acted upon.